# galenframework installation failed

Tags: node.js, galen

I am trying to install Galenframework. I had GalenFramework earlier which I uninstalled using :

```
npm uninstall-g galenframework-cli
```

Now when I am trying to install it again using

```
npm install-g galenframework-cli
```

I get the following error message:

```
info Install exited unexpectedly
npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\galenframework-cli\node_modules\ansi-styles\package.json'
npm WARN     at Error (native)
npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\galenframework-cli\node_modules\ansi-styles\package.json'
npm WARN     at Error (native)
npm WARN   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\galenframework-cli\\node_modules\\ansi-styles\\package.json\'\n    at Error (native)',
npm WARN   errno: -4048,
npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN   syscall: 'unlink',
npm WARN   path: 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\galenframework-cli\\node_modules\\ansi-styles\\package.json' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! galenframework-cli@2.3.5 postinstall: `node postinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the galenframework-cli@2.3.5 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-07T09_14_22_408Z-debug.log
```

What is causing the problem?

Comment: Have you follow this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/galenframework

Comment: Yes. I did. When execute the command to install galenframework, it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing with administration rights. Open a shell as admin

Also you could try the following thinks:

1. Disable any anti virus scanner
2. Change cache and retries:

`npm config set cache-lock-retries 1000
npm config set cache-lock-wait 100000`